# Notification Led toggle shell

Tags: shell, notifications, led

I want to toggle on my notificationled on my S7 android 6.0.1 with adb (shell). What command can I use or how is the led data stored to change the value. I have seen an treat, that it's stored in /sys/class/leds but I cannot change the value

Comment: I'm looking for this too, but you need to make sure you are root.

Comment: I am sure, i am root